# Upstart script for Sphinx

Tags: ubuntu, upstart, sphinx

I am trying to get Sphinx running with Upstart on Ubuntu, but the only script I've found isn't working and seems to be more complex than I require.

Could someone provide me with a basic Sphinx Upstart script that I can start with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I found a script base that I modified and instead of it saying "sphinxsearch start/waiting" it is giving me "sphinxsearch start/running" which I guess is good. The process dies immediately however which I think is due to the config I'm giving it. I will see if I can find a test config somewhere to conclude whether the upstart script works.

Current upstart script:

```
# sphinxsearch.conf

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

script
        su /usr/local/bin/searchd --config /etc/sphinx.conf 
end script

post-stop script
        su skerit -c 'sphinxsearch -kill :0'
end script

#End of File
```

Answer (score 0):

On my ubuntu ( 12.04 )

START=no   ->     START=yes

```
$ cat /etc/default/sphinxsearch 


#
# Settings for the sphinxsearch searchd daemon
# Please read /usr/share/doc/sphinxsearch/README.Debian for details.
#

# Should sphinxsearch run automatically on startup? (default: no)
# Before doing this you might want to modify /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf
# so that it works for you.
START=yes
```